# Spring framework: Bean Validation Api Error after executing Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi guys im newbie in using Spring framework, i tried to follow the the guides in there website

pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SpringTutorial.com</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-tutorial.com</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Spring Boot Tutorial</name>
<description>A simple tutorial for spring boot</description>

 <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

and i created Application.java inside src/main/java like this.

Application.java

```
package Application.com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

But when i run the application i get this error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Action:

Add an implementation, such as Hibernate Validator, to the classpath
```

I am using spring tool suite for the environment, what seems to be the problem here? thanks

Comment: what does your application.yml or application.properties looks like? Also please post the entire pom.xml

Comment: i dont have application.properties yet i just followed "Getting Started Guides" just the pom.xml and the application.java it should compile with no errors i think? and that's all the content in my pom.xml

Comment: by the way im using MAVEN

Answer (score -1):

I have deleted .m2/repository then builded again with 1.5.7.RELEASE then application started.
I think may be some redundancy issue while the reading jar file from Maven home path.